# Selenium - Identify a button

Tags: selenium

How can I identify this button using my Selenium program? There doesn't seem to be a unique property to identify the button. Is it advisible to use xpath?

```
<button class="md-primary md-raised md-button md-ink-ripple" ng-
transclude="" type="submit" aria-label="Login">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the label is unique, you can use this xpath:

```
//button[@aria-label='Login']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cssSelector`

```
// using the classes
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".md-primary.md-raised.md-button.md-ink-ripple"));

// using attributes
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[type='submit']"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[aria-label='Login']"));
```